# MacBook 4,1 running Linux Mint Freezes on shutdown

Tags: linux-mint, macintosh, shutdown, freeze, kernel-panic

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Final Step
[  OK  ] Finished Power-Off.
[  OK  ] Reached target Power-Off.
[27022.555948] sd-umoun[21227]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: device or resource busy
[27022.560980] sd-umoun[21228]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev/pts: Device or resource busy
[27022.563273] sd-umoun[21229]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
[27023.565921] shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize  file systems, ignoring
[27023.781186] hub 6-0:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -110)
[27024.808694] Kernel panic - not syncing: Timeout: not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler
_
```

```
 ] Stopped remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
 ] Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirror, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling
 ] Reached target Shutdown.
   Starting Shuts down the "live" preinstalled system cleanly...
 ] Finished Shuts down the "live" preinstalled system cleanly.
 ] Reached target Final Step
 ] Finished Power-Off.
 ] Reached target Power-Off.
1.287672] sd-umoun[3729]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: device or resource busy
1.289859] sd-umoun[3730]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev/pts: Device or resource busy
1.292206] sd-umoun[3731]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/dev: Device or resource busy
1.296931] shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize  file systems, ignoring
2.635950] hub 6-0:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -110)
```

I recently installed Linux Mint on a 2008 MacBook 4,1. It mostly works well but the shutdown process sometimes gets stuck right at the end.
I have searched around for a solution and have so far increased the default shutdown limit from 10s to 100s and also blacklisted the USB2 drivers (USB ports still work fine using the USB3 drivers). The problem happens about half the time. I dual boot with Mac OS X 10.7.5 and use ReFind as a boot manager although I can also boot from Grub.
From neofetch:

```
OS: Linux Mint 20.2 x86_64
Host: MacBook4,1 1.0
Kernel: 5.4.0-81-generic
Packages: 2371 (dpkg), 5 (flatpak)
Shell: bash 5.0.17
Resolution: 1280x800
DE: Xfce
WM: Xfwm4
WM Theme: Mint-Y
Theme: Mint-Y [GTK2/3]
Icons: Mint-Y [GTK2/3]
Terminal: xfce4-terminal
Terminal Font: Monospace 12
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo T8300 (2) @ 2.4 GHz
GPU: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960
Memory: 1431MiB / 3916MiB
```

I took a photo of the screen after it froze which might show what I need to do to fix it. I hope I posted in the right section.
Thanks in advance for any tips.

If not a fix for this particular problem, are there any configuration changes that would force the MacBook to shut down once the "`Reached target power off`" is posted. The second picture shows a kernel panic left as the last message before it froze.

Answer (score 1):

Please try setting `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` in your grub config. Then boot with grub and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: I put this into the /etc/default/grub file and then updated grub but it gave an error message. intel_idle.max_cstate=1 not found.

Comment: Put it inside GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Oops, I was premature, it didn't completely fix it. Are there any other changes I could make?

Comment: You could completely disable cstates with the same parameter, but with the value of 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this

```
sudo nano /etc/mkinitcpio.conf

change:
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard keymap filesystems fsck"
to:
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard keymap filesystems fsck shutdown"

sudo mkinitcpio -P
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

sudo systemctl restart systemd-coredump.socket
sudo systemctl reset-failed
```

Some users reported that it is a nvidia driver issue and they fixed it by removing the nvdia module in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf

[Link to the bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63697)

Comment: When I use [[sudo nano /etc/mkinitcpio.conf]] I get a blank file with nothing to edit.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.

Configuration:

/etc/initramfs/initramfs.conf

Mind that ...

/etc/initramfs/conf.d/

can be used for configuration files and

/etc/initramfs/conf-hooks.d/

for adding hooks. To rebuild you can use ...

 update-initramfs -u

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I tried that too but still no config file in Mint 20.02.